# Count two columns from two tables SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have data located in two tables which I would like to count and then display using a Google bar chart graph.  I have been struggling and couldn't find this case answered anywhere else.  The two tables have user_id in common, and I would like to count gam_id column from the first table (qsp_tiles), and mam_id from the second table (qsp_orders).  Here is a bit of code I am using:

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT t.user_id, COUNT ( o.gam_id) AS wake, COUNT( t.mam_id ) AS chuck, 
FROM #__qsp_tiles t
FULL JOIN #__qsp_orders o 
ON t.user_id=o.user_id 
");

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($result as $row){
$array[date("d D",$row->payment_date)]['wake'] += $row->wake;
$array[date("d D",$row->payment_date)]['chuck'] += $row->chuck;
}
foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
$out[] = "['{$k[payment_date]}', {$a[wake]}, {$a[chuck]}]";
}
?> 

<?php
echo implode(",", $out);
?>
```

Where the last bit should get turned into something like [5 Thu, 20, 50], this is what needs to go into the Google bar chart. I would like for it to spit out the last 5 days, but for now I just need to know how to do it for one day.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you're just trying to count the rows in each table I'd use two separate `select` statements to count the number of the rows like the following:

```
select count(gam_id) from qsp_tiles
```

and

```
select count(mam_id) from qsp_orders
```

If you want to count the number of rows that the both tables have in common I'd use the following statement (it's basically the same that you already used, just without the user_id field in the select and only one count):

```
select count(t.user_id) from qsp_tiles t inner join qsp_orders o on t.user_id = o.user_id
```